# why replace spaces with %20 program crashes?

Tags: c++, string

I wrote the following code to replace all the spaces in string s with string r (20%). E.g. s = "Mr John Smith", after running the code it should be "Mr20%John20%Smith".

My code crashes and it looks to me like a memory leak, but have no clue why it happens. Thank you.

```
void ReplaceStr(string &s, string &r)
{
    int i = 0;
    for(string::iterator it = s.begin(); it != s.end(); it++,i++)
    {
        if( *it == ' ')         
        {
            s.replace(i,1,r);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

The documentation for `replace` says "[a]ny iterators, pointers and references related to this object may be invalidated." Your iterator is an iterator into a version of the string that no longer exists, so you can't keep incrementing it, dereferencing it, comparing it, and so on.

Comment: So, I guess the answer would be to use indexing?

Comment: @Ben That would be one solution. Another would be to just keep searching for a space from the beginning each time until you don't find one.

Comment: @Ben Looks like make a new copy is much easier.

Comment: Another solution would be to `count` the number of spaces and `reserve` enough memory to accomplish the replacements without reallocation.

Comment: @Potatoswatter: That assumes that the one and only reason replace might invalidate the iterators is because it needed to reallocate.  While that seems obvious that would be true for a rational implementation, it's not an assumption I would rely on.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy The difference between `string` and `vector` there is certainly a defect (erratum) in the standard. It requires "allocated storage" to exist but doesn't require `string` to use it, whereas it does for `vector`.

Comment: @Potatoswatter:  I'm not sure what you're trying to say.  My point is that there may be reasons to invalidate iterators besides memory reallocation, which has nothing to do with differences between std::string and std::vector.

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy I'm saying the standard forbids iterator invalidation for any other reason for `vector`, and because there are no relevant differences between `vector` and `string`, the guarantee should be extended. Otherwise `string::reserve` is pretty much useless. (Copy-on-write string implementations may still be allowed, in which case the `vector` guarantee would be too strong. But `reserve` should still guarantee iterator preservation until capacity is full.)

Comment: @Potatoswatter:  The documentation for replace says it may invalidate iterators.  As far as I can tell, that's the entire contract with regard to iterator invalidation.  It would be dangerous to assume that reserving enough memory will guarantee that the iterators won't be invalidated.

Answer (score 1):

When the replacement length is not equal to the the target size, building a copy is generally easier and nearly as efficient.

```
void ReplaceSpaces(std::string &s, const std::string &r) {
  std::string result;
  result.reserve(s.size());
  for (char c : s) {
    if (c == ' ') result += r;
    else          result.push_back(c);
  }
  using std::swap;
  swap(s, result);
}
```

Comment: +1. Likely more efficient, considering that it doesn't require repeated copying of the end of the string.

Answer (score 0):

A much better option vould be not to use iterators at all:

```
void ReplaceStr(string &s, string &r)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < s.lenght(); )
    {
        if (s[i] == ' ')         
        {
            s.replace(i,1,r);
            i += r.lenght();
        }
        else
            i++;
    }
}
```

Quick and easy. Maybe r's lenght could be stored in a constant to improve the performance a little bit.

```
void ReplaceStr(string &s, const string &r)
{
    const int rSize = r.lenght();
    for (int i = 0; i < s.lenght(); )
    {
        if (s[i] == ' ')         
        {
            s.replace(i,1,r);
            i += rSize;
        }
        else
            i++;
    }
}
```

And this works because the leght of s gets constantly updated.

Comment: Be careful of using an `int` to index into a standard container.  The standard container sizes are typically `std::size_t`, which is unsigned and may be larger than an `int`.  When the capacity of the container exceeds a max int, you'll experience integer overflow, which gets you into undefined behavior.